# Horizontal text scroll inside EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am making an EditText field with custom background, but the input text is going to be longer then the field itself. Also, text needs to be in one line.

My idea is to make text "move to the left" when the line reach the end of the field. I saw in some applications that this is possible.

I searched for answers but non of them respond to this specific problem. After I combined few of them I tried to solve problem in this way:

```
<EditText 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>
```

But, when I type text and It reaches the end of EditText field, it starts to stretch my field ("@drawable/edit_text" in particular) until I reach 25 characters.

Also, when I change layout_width to some specific value, text goes in 2nd row when reach end (even if maxLines is still 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it. The point is that you need to put EditText inside RelativeLayout. Now It's working.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="21dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 16):

After some research, I found it working.

Using `android:inputType="text"` inside `EditText` worked for me.

Hope this will help someone and will save your time :)

Comment: Right! This will prevent the `\n` character making it one line text.  This should work.

Answer (score 3):

Put your EditText inside the `HorizontalScrollView` and it works..

```
            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/rlEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etPhone"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgBtnEdit"
                android:layout_below="@+id/etPhone" >
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:text="info@friedman.com"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: This worked. In fact, it's the only thing that worked. I didn't need the enabled="false" property but everything else was.

Comment: Man this really helped. By the way, this gives only horizontal scroll. But if you wrap it again with regular `ScrollView` - you get both. Now I feel that we're doing something wrong here, but heck, I learn Android dev only 2nd day, so far so good :)

Answer (score 2):

It worked after adding

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:singleLine="true"
android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
```

In

```
<EditText
        android:background="@drawable/sk"
        android:id="@+id/ed"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sed"
        android:textColor="@color/tc"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

to my edittext

Comment: sIngleLine is deprecated now

Comment: I know that but after removing that it doesn't worked I tested it on Samsung galaxy tab s and Samsung galaxy star pro

Comment: My question is : Why do i need to use "\\|" in String.split method but only "|"  in String.replace or String.indexOf method